# Tags cleaning: singular vs. plural

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

We have plenty of different tags, but while having a look at some of them, I realised that we have some

- in plural: e.g. [planets](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/planets), [gods](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gods), [cities](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cities), [humans](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/humans), ...
- in singular: e.g. [dragon](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dragon), [alien](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/alien), [spaceship](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/spaceship), [society](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/society), ...

I don't see any reason why we should have such a mix. There have been some discussion about it on meta, for example [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/41501/tagging-as-singular-or-plural) and [there](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6752/merge-singular-and-plural-tags?lq=1) (thanks HDE226868 for the links). There isn't a clear preference. Some even suggest to have synonyms between plural and singular forms.

I would prefer to avoid that. But what do you think, should we prefer singular or plural? In which cases? And if so, should we go on editing the ones that are "wrong"?

Comment: Like [Monica said](http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/2360/tags-cleaning-number#comment5462_2363), singular and plural forms as synonyms would be largely unnecessary. Synonyms should be used when the terms are completely different, like how we have `demographics` and `population`, or `shipbuilding` and `water-vessel-design` as synonyms.

Comment: I edited the question title to be somewhat more clear. Hope you don't mind, bilbo_pingouin.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling, of course not :-) More generally, is there a way to mass-edit all given tags?

Comment: I asked the question on [meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/261579/modify-all-occurences-of-a-tag).

Answer (score 13):

I don't think it really matters, but I vote for plural. I forget where I first heard this, but tags are supposed to attract people who can say "I am an expert in/on [tag]". You would not say "I am an expert on dragon".

Plus, the plural form is more encompassing. For instance, a question about how dragons interact with one another may not feel right under a 'dragon' tag, but a question about a single dragon definitely fits under a 'dragons' tag.

But like I said, I don't think it matters. This is one of those things people just auto-fix in their heads, and I don't want to go around editing posts just to add a single letter to the end of a tag.

Comment: Agreed on the reasoning you gave for plural.  I strongly prefer plural tags for countable nouns -- planets, moons, dragons, etc -- unless there really is only one.

Comment: I'd agree plural is the way to go overall. There should be a way to change all instances of a tag simultaneously, right? That way individual editing wouldn't be an issue

Comment: Your example is flawed. If I'm an expert sitting on a dragon, then I can say, "I am an expert on dragon." ;)

Comment: @Frostfyre that comment was totally superfluous but I laughed.

Comment: So what is required to make this change, can we simply edit the existing tag and have the change propagate to the relevant questions?

Comment: @James apparently the mods can do it. Normal users cannot do it recursively. Worse adding a 's' can't be done by normal edits according to meta.SE. See the wiki answer below.

Answer (score 4):

The agreement seems to be that tags should be used in their plural form. The [answer on meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/197731/285933) indicates that

> moderators can rename a tag

and assuming that that is the case, we could list below the tags that are in singular.

**To be renamed**

- [calendar](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/calendar)
- [civilization](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/civilization)
- [clone](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/clone)
- [crime](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/crime) to criminality?
- [culture](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/culture)
- [currency](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/currency)
- [economy](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/economy) is [countable](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/economy?q=economy) for countries economy = "economics" ?
- [government](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/government)
- [language](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/language)
- [population](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/population)
- [merfolk](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/merfolk) ? plural of folk is folk/folks...
- [radiation](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/radiation)
- [religion](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/religion) ? It might have a slightly different meaning...
- [sea](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sea)
- [solar-system](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/solar-system) The tag is confusing because there is only one Solar system, it's the system Earth is orbiting. But there are many star/stellar systems.
- [supernova](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/supernova) - "supernovae" and "supernovas" are both used as plurals.

**To be kept**

- [evolution](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/evolution) as it refers to The Evolution theory.
- [law](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/law) : There are several laws but there is the law in the broader sense. Law as an academic field for example can't be plural.
- [spaceflight](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/spaceflight) Is the action of flying in space.
- [society](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/society) because in its [meaning](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/society?q=society) about people living in communities in general, it is uncountable.

Comment: @Vincent, which is why I made it a community wiki, don't hesitate to modify.

Comment: I would argue that a lot of those singulars are abstract concepts, and thus making them plural is unnecessary. Like, if someone knows a lot of **religions** (Islam,  Judaism, etc), they can more simply state they are an expert on **religion**, as a field of knowledge.

Comment: @DaaaahWhoosh, yes some are not that easy. And religion is a particularly complex one. A question like Science vs Religion should have singular, but a question about Building-up a Religion, should have a plural. For me the fields of knowledge could be religious studies or theology. But, YMMV.

Comment: IMO, some could be changed to become uncountable : colony become colonization, crime become criminality

Comment: @Vincent, Isn't [tag:currencies] already in plural? And merfolk is a [form](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/folk) of [plural](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/folk_1?q=folk).

Comment: @bilbo_pingouin my mistake, it's currency.

Comment: @DaaaahWhoosh, sorry parallel editing. Nevertheless, [radiation](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/radiation) can also be countable: *the radiations emitted by radium*.

Comment: @bilbo_pingouin I agree it *can* be countable, I just think in this case the tag is more about the phenomenon of radiation rather than a set of instances of radiation. I may have to modify my answer here, there are a lot of cases I hadn't considered.

Comment: Thank you for compiling this list.  I agree with the earlier comment that some of these are abstract concepts or otherwise not countable *the way we use them here*.  For example, "language" and "languages" mean two different things, ditto "religion" and "religions" (already raised).  I think "crime" is fine as an abstract concept and needn't change to the more-unwieldy criminality.  But a lot of these should be changed, so thanks again.