# Should we rename [insect] to [insects]?

Tags: discussion, specific-tag, tags

On the Main Site we have a tag named [insect](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/insect). Normally tags should be plural, not singular. See [Tags cleaning: singular vs. plural](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2360/tags-cleaning-singular-vs-plural) for more information.

The [tag wiki](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/tags/insect/info) excerpt even says:

> For questions focused on insects.

And the full tag wiki says:

> For questions specifically focused on insects: behaviour, body structures and features, evolution, communication, etc.

Do we want to rename the tag from [insect](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/insect) to [insects](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/insects)?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Agreed -- tags that are counting nouns should generally be plural.  I just renamed it.

Comment: Thanks for that!